# no listbox items after assigning datasource c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, listbox, datasource

I've been trying for a while to populate a listbox with a datatable.

Here is my code as suggested by almost every page I've seen:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Files", con))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable tblShapes = new DataTable();
    dap.Fill(tblShapes);

    lb.DataSource = tblShapes;

    // define Display and Value members
    lb.DisplayMember = "Name";
    lb.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

The problem is that there is no items in `lb.Items` even though `lb.datasource.rows` has my records
I also tried to change the order of assigning `datasource` with `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` nothing changes

c# winforms

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your ListBox control isn't added to any form.  It just dies an unhappy life.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks alot, it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dynamically creating lsitbox you need to add to a control, also set the DataSource later

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
this.Controls.Add(lb);
lb.DisplayMember = "Name";
lb.ValueMember = "Id";
lb.DataSource = tblShapes;
```